# Tab content appears only when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I'm using a jquery easytabs plugin (http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/), and I want to make the content of tabs appear only after I click in some tab.

If I set the event onclick() it probably can stop the easytabs() function. I tried it and it's not working. Then I tried to add that code:

```
onclick="$('#tab').removeClass('beforeclick');
```

inside easytabs() method, but it seems not working.

How can I do it without stop easytabs?

I apologize because I could not make it work in http://jsfiddle.net.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: show us the problem in a jsfiddle and show the whole code of the tabs.

Comment: I was running the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/c9pkc

Comment: But still lack what I need when the user accesses the site the first tab can not be activate, can only activate when they click. Can anyone help?